# AMRestoreErrorDomain error 26 when restoring or reviving M1 macbook pro with apple configurator 2

Tags: macbook-pro, restore, apple-silicon, apple-configurator

I am trying to revive my m1 macbook pro after it started showing exclamation mark icon with restore url.

Now I am trying to revive it using my other intel-based macbook using apple configurator 2 but on step 3 installation, it fails and shows this error.

```
The System cannot be restored on this device.


The operation couldn’t be completed. (AMRestoreErrorDomain error 26 - Failed to handle message type StatusMsg (fsck failed)) [AMRestoreErrorDomain – 0x1A (26)]
```

I also tried restore, but the error persists.

**Specs and things I tried**

- Intel-based Mac OS version: Big Sur 11.4
- Apple Configurator 2: Version 2.14
- IPSW Files Tested:
  `UniversalMac_11.3.1_20E241_Restore.ipsw`
  `UniversalMac_11.4_20F71_Restore.ipsw`
- Tried changing cables

Anyone run into this, or have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: why are you going that very complicated route? Just reinstall macOS from recovery mode: https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/28/startup-modes-for-m1-macs/

Comment: i tried opening the boot options, but boot options are not working for me either. Same exclamation logo appears after it says "Loading boot options"

Comment: If it can't boot into the recovery partition then something is messed up and I am sorry but I can't help you. What you may try is to create a boot pen drive and try booting from there.

Comment: Yeah it looks like recovery partition is corrupted. I tried creating pen drive but in order to boot it you need to open boot options, once you do, same error appears. I might need to go to Apple store

Comment: I read your answer like you have a second MacBook. Why can't you create a boot USB there?

Comment: I have created usb from my second machine, but the problem is, my M1 machine is not booting into boot options or recovery. And for booting from usb, i need the open the boot option on m1 which are broken. So i am just left with DFU mode to recover it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to resolve the issue. Apparently, the issue was related to host macOS not the bricked M1 MacBook.

➡️ **I created another user account; and tried to restore. One 3rd attempt it worked!**

I am not sure what was the problem, but here are the step that led me to success.

- Updated the macOS Big Sur to the latest version
- Restarted host mac after clearing cache and temp directories
- Removed and re-downloaded the latest IPSW file
- Created another user account for recovery
- Tried Revive multiple times with no success
- Tried Restore; success on third attempt

I hope Apple will fix these random issues with configurator as there is very little help whatsoever with configurator, and its really frustrating..!